# c# change pictureBox DataBinding on click

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a pictureBox which I set the DataBindings via Properties in Visual Studio, to a specific image type field of my table. So far so good, its bringing the image of the database.

But I need this pictureBox to change what image it brings depending on what button was clicked. I have 4 image fields on my table. If user click button1, I need this pictureBox to be Databinded with field image1 of my table. If user click button 2, change its Databing and bring the image saved on image2 field of the table.

How can I do that?

Comment: I was thinking in put 4 pictureBoxes, each one alread DataBinded with the correct field of the table, and put then visible=false, change to true on click, but, this form have alot of tools, pencil, erase and some drawString. I do not want to duplicate all this tools, i´d like to use this tools on the pictureBox, no matter what image is brough, and save in the correct tabble field.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider introducing an Image Handler as described here: https://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

The ImageHandler would be used to determine, which image is returned to the client application.  For example, if button one is clicked then image 1 is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class like this:

```
public class ImageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChaged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int state = 0;
    public int State 
    { 
        set
        {
            this.state = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("State");
            this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentBitmap");
        }
        get
        {
            return this.state;
        }
    }
    public Bitmap SelectedBitmap
    {
        get
        {
            if(this.state = 0)
                return Bitmap1; //You have to add the logic for Bitmap1
            else if(this.state = 1)
                return Bitmap2; //You have to add the logic for Bitmap1
            else if(this.state = 2)
                return Bitmap3; //You have to add the logic for Bitmap1
            else if(this.state = 3)
                return Bitmap4; //You have to add the logic for Bitmap1
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

then you have to bind your PictureBox on SelectedBitmap

Comment: I was thinking on something simpler, like picBox.Table.Field.image1, after btn click, picBox.table.Field.Image2. I just have 4 image type cells in my table, want to change what cell this picBox will bring with a button.